# Combining Two List Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to combine two lists based on an ID in table 2 showing up in table1.

```
table1 = [(u'Id1', u'New'),(u'Id4', u'New')]
table2 = [(u'Id1', u'Proudct1', None, u'New', u'Id#343', u'Jim'),
          (u'Id2', u'Proudct2', None, u'New', u'Id#3343', u'Jim')]

Combined = [item for item in table2 if item[0] in table1]
print Combined
```

Results:

```
[]
```

Desired Results:

```
[(u'Id1', u'Proudct1', None, u'New', u'Id#343', u'Jim')]
```

Comment: Try `[item[0] for item in table2]` and ask yourself (or Python!) if any are `in table1`.

Comment: `Combined = [item for item in table2 if any(x[0] == item[0] for x in table1)]` should work

Comment: im not sure a list is the proper data structure to use here ...

Comment: i would start by extracting the ids: `ids = set(x[0] for x in table1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue happens to be here:

```
if item[0] in table1
```

Instead you should compare `item[0]` which is the 1st item of tuple with the 1st item in table1 too

```
if item[0] in [elment[0] for element in table1]
```

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion requires creating the `[elment[0] for element in table1]` list over and over again for each entry in `table2`.

Answer (score 3):

ok fine

```
table1 = [(u'Id1', u'New'),(u'Id4', u'New')]
table2 = [(u'Id1', u'Proudct1', None, u'New', u'Id#343', u'Jim'),(u'Id2', u'Proudct2', None, u'New', u'Id#3343', u'Jim')]
#convert to dictionaries (a more appropriate data structure,imho at least)
dict1=dict(table1)
dict2=dict((item[0],item[1:]) for item in table2)
#get the intersection
final = dict((key,dict2[key]+(dict1[key],)) for key in set(dict1).intersection(dict2))
print final
```

you will probably see significant speed gains if your tables are large

Answer (score 1):

If your tables will always have the format you're showing, you could do this:

```
Combined = []
for entry1 in table1:
  for entry2 in table2:
    if entry1[0]==entry2[0]:
      Combined.append(entry2)
print Combined
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if item[0] in table1` clause is testing if strings like `u'Id1'` and `u'Id2'` can be found in the list `table1`.  But `table1` is a list of tuples, which means you are comparing strings with tuples.  Needless to say, `str == tuple` will always evaluate to `False`.

To fix the problem, you can use another list comprehension like so:

```
>>> table1 = [(u'Id1', u'New'),(u'Id4', u'New')]
>>> table2 = [(u'Id1', u'Proudct1', None, u'New', u'Id#343', u'Jim'),(u'Id2', u'Proudct2', None, u'New', u'Id#3343', u'Jim')]
>>> ids = [x[0] for x in table1]
>>> Combined = [item for item in table2 if item[0] in ids]
>>> Combined
[('Id1', 'Proudct1', None, 'New', 'Id#343', 'Jim')]
>>>
```

In the above code, `ids` will be a list of the id strings found in `table1`:

```
>>> table1 = [(u'Id1', u'New'),(u'Id4', u'New')]
>>> ids = [x[0] for x in table1]
>>> ids
['Id1', 'Id4']
>>>
```

So, the `if item[0] in table1` clause is now testing if `item[0]` can be found in a list of strings.

---

Note however that `in` will be performing an `O(n)` (linear) search through `ids` for each item in `table2`.  This could be slow.  A better approach would be to use a set of ids:

```
ids = {x[0] for x in table1}
```

Sets have `O(1)` (constant) lookup time with `in`, so they are more efficient with repeated lookups.

Answer (score 0):

I added one more element to table2 to  make sure that the combined_list get what desired.

```
table1 = [(u'Id1', u'New'), (u'Id4', u'New')]
table2 = [(u'Id1', u'Proudct1', None, u'New', u'Id#343', u'Jim'),
          (u'Id2', u'Proudct2', None, u'New', u'Id#3343', u'Jim'),
          (u'Id4', u'Proudct4', None, u'New', u'Id#44444', u'Jim')]

comined_list = []
for i in table1:
    for j in table2:
        if i[0] == j[0]:
            comined_list.append(j)
print comined_list
```

The output:

[(u'Id1', u'Proudct1', None, u'New', u'Id#343', u'Jim'), (u'Id4', u'Proudct4', None, u'New', u'Id#44444', u'Jim')]

Answer (score 0):

```
table1 = [(u'Id1', u'New'),(u'Id4', u'New')]
table2 = [(u'Id1', u'Proudct1', None, u'New', u'Id#343', u'Jim'),(u'Id2', u'Proudct2', None, u'New', u'Id#3343', u'Jim')]
st = {a for b in table1 for a in b}
print([x for x in table2 if x[0] in st])
[(u'Id1', u'Proudct1', None, u'New', u'Id#343', u'Jim')]
```